# Angular js - Passing service as controller parameter casuing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, login-script, angular-services

When adding 'loginService' as parameter to the controller to reference the service I want to use, it seems to cause an error as none of the rest of my angular functions work.

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope, loginService){

   $scope.loginUser = function () {
       loginService.login();
   }
});
```

However removing the service as parameter as shown below doesn't crash the rest of the sites angular functions, but obviously doesn't do the job I need.

```
app.controller('loginController', function ($scope){

   $scope.loginUser = function () {
       loginService.login();
   }
});
```

The service script has been declared.
I'm very new to this and would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Need to see service code.

Comment: When you see this problem, is the javascript being minified? Are you familiar with the Array syntax to specify the things to inject? The array syntax works when the javascript is minified. Your syntax above won't work when the javascript is minified.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the array syntax you're talking about, could you give me an example please?

Comment: First line of your controller would look like this when using the array notation: `app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', 'loginService', function ($scope, loginService){`  The last line of your controller then needs the closing `]` to close the array and looks like this: `}]);`

Comment: The idea is that when you minify your javascript, the variable names will be shortened. Since the variable names get changed, Angular no longer knows how to find the things to inject. So you give it an array, where the first `n` items are strings of things you want to inject. The last item is function that has `n` number of variables as arguments.

Comment: @SunilD. that is true, but that isn't the problem here. Additionally, ng-min allows you to code without the array syntax and it will add the array syntax at build time.

Comment: @aaronfrost neat! Checking out ng-min now, though that array notation is forever engrained in my brain...

Comment: @SunilD. at work we have a VERY LARGE app. Over 100,000 of JavaScript. Out Grunt build runs all of our Angular code through ng-min. We never use the array syntax. It makes me sad that some people have to do it every day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you copy the following code into the same file as your loginController code, does it work?

```
app.factory('testCtrl', function (){

    return {
        login: function(){
            console.log("DO SOMETHING GOOD WITH REGARDS TO LOGGING IN");
        }
    };
});
```

Then inject testCtrl into your controller. If it works, then We need to see your service.

Comment: Your code is identical to my service code. Your code works if pasted on the same page as the loginController however if I put it in the services file it still doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It is hard to see without your html and service file. Do you have your ng-app declaration done correctly? Or are you manually bootstraping the app?

Comment: This has a working example of what you want to see. Not sure where you are doing your code different. I have tried to make the example as simple as possible. Please remove the down-vote on this answer. It messes with the score on the forum. http://plnkr.co/edit/74hxKXwOVvKkvcHR9L3u?p=preview

Comment: Got it working now with the help of your solution, had made a few silly mistakes. Thanks a lot!